# UI doesn't re-render after query - React Query

Tags: react-query, next.js13

For some reason my UI doesn't re-render after I use the update mutation. The data does change when I watch it via useEffect. However 'invalidateQueries' doesn't seem to work

```
 const [todos, setTodos] = useState(useTodoStore);

  //watch todos
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("todos", todos);
  }, [todos]);

  function getTodos() {
    return Promise.resolve(todos);
  }

  function updateTodo(todo: any) {
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    const newTodos = todos.map((t: any) => (t.id === todo.id ? todo : t));
    setTodos(newTodos);
    return Promise.resolve(todo);
  }

  function deleteTodo(id: number) {
    const newTodos = todos.filter((todo: any) => todo.id !== id);
    setTodos(newTodos);
    return Promise.resolve(id);
  }

  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["todos"],
    queryFn: getTodos,
  });

  const updateMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (newTodo) => {
      return updateTodo(newTodo);
    },
    onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ["todos", data.id],
      });
    },
  });

  const deleteMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (id: number) => {
      return deleteTodo(id);
    },
    onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ["todos", data],
      });
    },
  });
```

I've tried to use 'onSettled' instead of 'onSuccess' but nothing happens

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.